# Load sensor ADC converter

Tags: adc, load-cell

Load sensor required external module HX711 (ADC converter 24bit for weight) for ADC converter. This module is then connected to the controller.

If I have a controller with inbuilt 24bit ADC, then is it OK to interface load sensor directly with the controller's ADC pin?

Or is it compulsory to connect external ADC converter, or any specific application that HX711 compulsory connect?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is *compulsory*.

You just *design* your circuits to match your performance needs.  Sensing analog things is hard and noisy, and you will get more noise if you have long cables between sensor and ADC. That makes a strong argument for placing the ADC as close as possible to the sensor.

Whether that is *necessary*, however, is something we can't tell you: We don't know the sensor, the ADCs involved, the noise you can tolerate, the rate of measurements you need to achieve, what the precision is you need, how much effort you can put into calibrating things...

Comment: Thanks Marcus for your answer. i have seen lots of datasheet and articles related to load cell measurement. i have noticed than load cell required 24bit ADC. so is then any limitation of load cell that can be fulfilled only by 24bit ADC. can i have to use 16 or 20bit ADC instead of 24bit.

Comment: Re-read my answer.

Comment: You can add supply stability to the mix and/or additional voltage sensing feedback right from the inputs of a load cell, as it is often done in load cell amplifiers. Way too many things to consider if using MCU alone as opposed to dirt cheap off-shelf amplifier

Answer (score 0):

> Or is it compulsory to connect external ADC converter, or any specific application that HX711 compulsory connect?

It is not compulsory. You can use any other external `ADC` or your MCU's internal ADC. It's very application/problem specific. To answer it, I need to know your complete design requirements. May be steps given below help you in getting an answer.

- First you need to calculate the distance required between your `Load Sensor` and your point of conversion for your application (That distance shouldn't be very long as it will reduce `SNR` of your signal). The signal has to be traveled in `Analog` form from Load Sensor to point of conversion (ADC). You need to be careful in layout. The noise can be coupled to your signal and there won't be any way to remove that noise once it is added to your signal. There are many guides online which can help you to layout sensitive signals.
- If you can place MCU near to the point of conversion, then you can use MCU's internal ADC but still you need to consider `ADC` requirement of the design. If you can't place MCU near to point of conversion, then you have to use external ADC for your design.
- To compare internal ADC and external ADC, you need to compare them using following parameters: DNL, INL, Offset Error, Gain Error, Temperature drift, Resolution, Max. Sampling Rate, Conversion Time, Power Consumption, BOM cost, PCB Space and various other parameters. Read [this](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/748) to know more. Once you find out these parameters, then you need to compare them with your application requirements: Power Consumption (This may help you with battery life of your product if it requires battery and good battery life), BOM cost (required for cost-sensitive product), Resolution required (The resolution required depends upon smallest weight that can be measured. You need to consider [Effective Number of Bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_number_of_bits) of ADC), Product Size (This will decide PCB size and distance between load sensor and point of conversion and from point of conversion to MCU), Sampling Rate (Your application may require x number of ADC samples per seconds. Then, your ADC should be faster than X samples per sec), Temperature drift (Your ADC may change it's value if temperature changes. You can calibrate via a temperature sensor and a algorithm to cancel out temperature effect).

I have included some keywords and pointers that may help you in finding a solution for your application. I can't answer your question because it requires large amount of information regarding your application.

**EDIT**

> i have seen lots of datasheet and articles related to load cell measurement. i have noticed than load cell required 24bit ADC. so is then any limitation of load cell that can be fulfilled only by 24bit ADC. can i have to use 16 or 20bit ADC instead of 24bit.

Resolution helps you with smallest possible measurement that you can make with an ADC. For example, the temperature sensor which outputs voltage (linearly) proportional to the temperature. (0 V = 0 C & 5 V = 100 C). If you are using 10 bit ADC, then smallest temperature change that you could measure is `(100 - 0) / (2^10) = 0.0976 C`. However, same temperature sensor with 24-bit ADC can measure  `(100 - 0) / (2^24) = 0.0000059 C` temperature difference.

Answer (score 0):

if u go through HX711 module ,you would observe it that it has in build amplifier and ADC . load cell output is very less (nearly 0 to few mV). so it need to be amplified and then sent to the ADC if you are not using HX711. Precision (Instrumentation) amplifier would help you in case you are not using the HX711 Module.